# Filter Divs by class using either URL or select list

Tags: jquery, select, filter, hide, show

I have a page that shows lots of divs and need to have the ability to filter these by either a url query string and also 2 select list inputs.

I have it working where a it will add ?dc=classnamehere which then shows only divs with that class - the jquery for this below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('dc');
 
     $(document).ready(function() {
 
        // Check if the URL parameter is apples
        if (dynamicContent == 'westbury') {
            $('.westbury').show();
        } 
        // Check if the URL parameter is oranges
        else if (dynamicContent == 'clifton') {
            $('.clifton').show();
        } 

        // Check if the URL parmeter is empty or not defined, display default content
        else {
            $('.listing-item').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I also need is the ability to show/hide these same divs by two select lists as below - both targeting classes aswell.

```
                       <select id="area">
<option value="">Select Area</option>
    <option value="westbury">Westbury</option> 
    <option value="clifton">Clifton</option>
</select>
<select id="category">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    <option value="cafe">cafe</option>
    <option value="shop">shop</option>  
</select>
```

So basically if I visit the page and it has in the url ?dc=classhere I will be shown results for that class - then if I select a filter via the select list it can then override and show/hide divs based on that.

If nothing is selected or shown in the url then everything can be shown.

Thanks in advance!